# Regression for model of form $y = Ax^n + Bx + C$

Tags: regression

I am trying to calculate the coefficients $A, B$ and $C$ for the model $\ y = Ax^n + Bx + C$.

For a simple power law of the form $\ y = Ax^n $ I can perform log-log regression to calculate $A$. And for a model of the form $\ y = Bx + C $ I can perform simple linear regression to calculate $B$ and $C$.

What I do not understand is how I can combine these models to calculate $A, B$ and $C$ together. Is it OK to combine the results from the separate models or do I need a different approach?

Comment: Combination of separate models will not work. Typically this is an exercise in nonlinear regression. All four parameters must be estimated together.

Comment: What is your preferred programming language or statistical software package?

Comment: I disagree with @NickCox provided you are indeed only interested in A, B and C. If you know $n$ you can just use linear regression using $x^n$ and $x$ as independents. If you do **not** know $n$ that becomes a different matter and you would need non-linear regression

Comment: @Maarten Punt Indeed if $n$ is regarded as known then it is not to be estimated. I don't disagree on that. Rather, the question is ambiguous if that is not clear. But usually log-log regression is used to estimate $A$ and $n$. What  the question and all comments so far leave open is what assumptions about error seem plausible.

Comment: Based on the comments so far, please edit your question to specify: (1) whether you already know the value of $n$ or if that needs to be estimated from the data, and (2) the nature of the measurements of both variables, which should help clarify how the error terms around the predictions of your model might be distributed. The underlying theory of why you expect this form of model to hold would also help. Please add that information to the question rather than leaving it in a comment, so that future visitors to the site can find it more readily.